# Noita Eye Glyphs

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, unsolved-mysteries

A puzzle found hidden between the background layers of the computer game [Noita](https://noitagame.com/). The puzzle has not been solved since it was added to the game in October of 2020.

It is made of thousands of eye images, each eye looking in one of five directions, presented in nine rectangular blocks scattered throughout the game world. The game's developers have confirmed that the "eye decorations" do contain a message, and we have every indication that they are some kind of cipher puzzle.

[image: Eye glyphs, as seen in game]
It looks like nine ciphertexts, composed of a total of 3,108 eyeballs.

Players of Noita have documented many attempts to understand the eye glyphs, and most if not all of the community's efforts are listed in a document titled [The Emerald Tablet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Aih_3v9BMbVI-MQQgWP51HTTplgRwXi2jRKYgyhPMao/edit#gid=0).

Some notable documents from that list:

[Noita Eye Glyph Messages](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1s6gxrc1iLJ78iFfqC2d4qpB9_r_c5U5KwoHVYFFrjy0/edit#) recounts the discovery of the glyphs and the initial "trigram" interpretation, which has so far proven correct.

[Noita Eye Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/195Rtc8kj4b74LtIyakqGP-iHhm36vyT5i8w7H5JjOV8/edit#gid=202652133) contains the eye glyphs in numerical form at every stage between raw eyeballs and trigrams.

[The Eye Messages page on the Noita wiki](https://noita.wiki.gg/wiki/Eye_Messages) gives more information about the puzzle and how to find it in game, and talks about some of the more notable observations.

Extensive cryptographic analysis (a large part of it done and/or reproduced by the current author) has failed to identify the cipher method used as any of the hundreds of specific, known ciphers that have been used either in puzzles or in cryptographic history. On the other hand, the analysis found a number of unusual qualities that have cryptographic significance.

My own document, [Analytical Overview](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QeagH8TklJsd8iribMtT5LIRL91laOUU_tFcVl7OOqA/edit#heading=h.kube2smqfujy) includes a summary of previous work followed by the results of various statistical methods and other observations on the glyphs, and also doubles as a book report on William F. Friedman's old codebreaking manuals.

The most significant oddity found in the eye glyphs are a set of patterns called *isomorphs*, a word with a very specific technical meaning in the context of classical ciphers that none of the solvers even knew about until it was found in Friedman's work. My other document, [Isomorphism in Classical Ciphers](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1a4uOf7SkXEPCROEi1iHzU5Lbr3zMbtOqSq_J5c4kyOw/edit#), tries to explain the causes and significance of isomorphism to the casual reader.

[image: Prominent isomorphs with distinctive letter patterns]

Other items of note are the relative lack of repetitions other than the shared message openings, the low Index of Coincidence overall and within each message, and the low Kappa IoC when comparing each message to every other message (which suggests the messages do not share a key).

As far as we can tell, the "decorations" (as the developers call them) have absolutely no effect on gameplay.

Good luck!

Comment: I added this to the [list of bounties with no deadlines](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4399/list-of-bounties-with-no-deadlines) with a 500rep reward

Comment: Props on your Analytical Overview doc - *very* easy to read and understand given the complex (and to me somewhat unfamiliar) subject matter.

Comment: @Lukas I'll match your reward.

Comment: Could the solution potentially require any in-game knowledge ([tag:knowledge])?

Comment: Probably not.  We've spent the last few years combing through the game, its assets, and its code looking for anything that would have even a tenuous connection to the eye glyphs, and came up empty. I also heard a reference to a quote from the devs saying something like "everything you need to solve it is right here" but I haven't been able to find the source.

Comment: A user in [the game's Discord](https://discord.com/invite/noita) did some detective work and found a vague connection between Noita and PSE. One of the game's developers is Hempuli, who has designed several pen-and-paper grid logic puzzles. He credits [@Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11876/deusovi) for a correction to one of his [Lohkous](https://www.hempuli.com/blogblog/archives/2422) puzzles, and at some point Deusovi creates [a puzzle using Hempuli's *Curfew* ruleset](https://deusovi.github.io/puzzlefiles/curfew.html). We don't know whether Hempuli created the eye puzzle.

Comment: @codewarrior0 If it helps [there was an update about the Noita Eye Glyphs puzzle 10 days ago](https://youtu.be/ctmmguuF1e8?si=6OOqDvmdR1YQSDl8) (not sure if you've already seen it or not), also will match your reward for the bounty.

Comment: Right, the update is that we can now predict where in the game world each of the nine messages will be found, given only the world's "seed" value, and without needing to launch the game at all. It's not directly useful for deciphering the eyes, but we can at least search for a seed where all of the messages are easy to get to.